# how to retrieve the token generated while using django allauth and django-rest-auth with django rest framework

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am using `django allauth` and `django-rest-auth` from this tutorial to generate a token for `django rest framework`. The tutorial can be found on this page, at the bottom. (https://www.softcover.io/read/92780ad5/django_book/token_authentication)

I am able to generate the token after accessing `api/dj-rest-auth/register/`, which is the sign up page from the browsable API.

[image]

[image]

Now the issue is that i am on `python3 manage.py shell` and i am trying to retrieve any of the token generated for either user `test001` or `test002`

does any one know how to do it? I am having a hardtime to achieve it

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tokens_for_user1_and_user2 = APIToken.objects.filter(user__name__in=["test001","test002"]).all()
```

I guess ... or something like that

Comment: yes, for my future self: do the import first `from dj_rest_auth.models import TokenModel`, then the query is `TokenModel.objects.filter(user_id__username='test001')`